# permission denied for window type 2038 - Android TV

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, android-tv

I am attempting to develop floating "widgets" for an android TV (android 8) and every time I try to run the app I'm prompted with:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.floatingwidget2020, PID: 11548
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service com.example.floatingwidget2020.FloatingWindow: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@e7b96bd -- permission denied for window type 2038
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3414)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap4(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1683)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
 Caused by: android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@e7b96bd -- permission denied for window type 2038
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:789)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:356)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:92)
    at com.example.floatingwidget2020.FloatingWindow.onCreate(FloatingWindow.java:57)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3404)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap4(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1683) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

When I initially run the emulator the console prompts with:

```
E/eglCodecCommon: glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
glUtilsParamSize: unknow param 0x000082da
```

Snippet of what I believe to be resulting in the issue:

```
final WindowManager.LayoutParams parameters = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(400, 150, WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
```

and in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

When I change flag to WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE it works fine on phone, but no go on android TV.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

On AndroidTV (Oreo) this is the correct configuration:

```
mFloatingView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.notification_item, null);        
final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
    500,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.END;
params.y = -354;
mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
mWindowManager.addView(mFloatingView, params);
```

This is what we use (production) to show some custom notifications. Actually you also make sure the user gave you the permission.